# Class initialisation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I create two classes like so:

```
class Example
{


}

class OtherExample
{
    init() {
        println("created")
    }
}

var instance = Example()
var otherInstance = OtherExample()
```

Both seem to create usable instances, so I'm wondering what the difference is in Swift if you *don't* provide an init method, and yet you initialise as above?

I did think it probably called the superclass init automatically, however since both of these objects don't inherit from NSObject, they don't have super classes do they?!

Also is there a need to class `super.init()` in the otherExample?

Comment: Also the first character of a class should be uppercase. Use `Example` and `OtherExample` instead of `example` and `otherExample`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need `super.init()` if your class inherits from another class.

```
class Example {
  func sayHi() {
    print("hi")
  }
}

class OtherExample: Example {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    print("created")
  }
}

var instance = Example()
instance.sayHi()
// hi

var otherInstance = OtherExample()
otherInstance.sayHi()
// created
// hi
```

Comment: Ok, so what method is called when I create the instance like this?                 var instance = example()  - I thought the init method did the actual creation of the object, with no init, what is called to create the object?

Comment: I think this is just syntactic sugar. Having no init actually means having `init() {}`. That's why the second class has to *override* the `init` method, even if we don't see it.

Comment: @Woodstock your code does not do the actual creation of the object. The swift runtime creates the objects for you, and calls the init method half way through the process (if there is an init method). In Objective-C (which has almost exactly the same runtime as swift) objects were created by executing the `alloc` method and then the `init` method. In theory you could override `alloc` for object creation however nobody ever did so in practice so this facility was not brought over to Swift. If you're just curious, I recommend reading Apple's Objective-C Runtime document. Swift is mostly the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
class example{
    var example:Int = 0
}

class anotherExample{
    init(example:Int){
        self.example = example
    }
    var example:Int
}

example()
anotherExample(0)
```

You can have not initialized variables in a class with an initializer, if you don’t have any initializer you will need to set a value in the class

Both will be able to change their example value but only `anotherExample` will have a value that can be set.
In my test playground I was unable to use super.init() in the classes (since they don’t have any superclasses to init to/from)

Comment: `super.init()` works in a Playground, of course. The class just needs to inherit from any other class.

Comment: super.init() doesn’t work, I was unable to use it. This will not work with any root class

Comment: Please read my comment again, the second part... [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/b726b159-751f-4043-8e9a-e666a565f669/36ff429513a12f466f4ff0b94f76c28b/deep/0/mnvknbhvkhv.playground.png). :)

Comment: Sorry I miss understood you, what I meant to say is that I was unable to use `super.init()` inside the class since it didn’t extend any superclasses. It does indeed work in Playground if you extend a superclass, I was aware of this

Comment: @milo526 No problem, I was sure it was just a misunderstanding, but I wanted to make things clear. :)